# Is this question better framed: How did “to lie” (i.e lie about something) and “to lie” (i.e. lie down) end up being spelled the same way?

Tags: discussion

I have edited the question to more thoroughly explain what I am asking for, and what research I've already done.

Question: [How did "to lie" (i.e lie about something) and "to lie" (i.e. lie down) end up being spelled the same way?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93642/how-did-to-lie-i-e-lie-about-something-and-to-lie-i-e-lie-down-end-up-b)

Would love for it to be re-opened, if it is now better framed. If not, please let me know how I can make it better.

Comment: Nice work. One vote down, four more to go...

Comment: Hi J.R. Are you implying that the question is still not very well framed? Would love your input.

Comment: No, I'm telling you that I just voted to reopen your question. :^)

Comment: Oh, I see. :) Thanks. You can tell I'm a n00b.

Comment: It's open now. Thank you for taking the time to improve it!

Comment: @J.R. The consecutive words "vote down" might not be the best choice in StackExchange context for something other than downvoting. I happened to see the comment and caught the wrong meaning at first, too. Ahhh, our English idioms. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see how any amount of editing can make it a "good" question.

Two different words (meaning *rest horizontally* and *tell untruths*) just happen to have both the same sound *and the same spelling*. So what?

If anyone asked *"How come **to, too** and **two** all sound the same?"*, I doubt it would remain open on ELU for long. Those words only happen to have *different* spellings because of historical "accidents", not because someone decided to make sure they could always be differentiated in a written context.

My guess is my *to/too/two* version might survive on [linguistics.se](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/), because there is something inherently interesting about the fact that language (English, at least) is able to make use of ambiguous/overlapping symbols. But if that had already been asked and answered there, OP's *lie/lie* question would probably be closed as a duplicate thereof.